# Alternative ways to find Matrix min max using Java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, max, min

```
package myArray;
// https://github.com/javadevelopcom/ArrayVsArrayList/blob/master/src/myArray/MatrixMinMax.java
public class MatrixMinMax {

    public static void matrixMinMax() {
        System.out.println("Matrix is a rectangular array of numbers, symbols, or expressions:" + "\n");

        int[][] matrix = {
                {10, 10, 10, 10, -10},
                {20, 20, 20, -20, 20},
                {30, 30, -30, 30, 30},
                {40, -40, 40, 40, 40},
                {-50, 50, 50, 50, 50}};

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
        int min = matrix[0][0];
        int max = matrix[0][0];

        for (int[] ints : matrix) {
            for (int i : ints) {
                if (i < min) {
                    min = i;
                }
                if (i > max) {
                    max = i;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("MIN: " + min);
        System.out.println("MAX: " + max);
    }
}
```

Matrix Array min max, Two-dimensional array

Comment: Result: min:-50; max:50;

Comment: What is wrong with your approach? It seems to give you the correct result...

Comment: Do you want a better running time, because so far it is correct?

Comment: time needed is O(n), difficult to do less.

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina I believe that now for a (n*n) matrix he would be in O(n^2).

Comment: precisely, O(number of datas) = O (size x size)

Comment: I want check (testing) alternative methods of it

Comment: I don't understand. What is your question? What's wrong with this code? Do you want to improve it? It's best to edit your question than commenting it. This way everyone can understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is mere speculation, depending on overall context, it would be possible not to search maximum and minimum in the actual data member

```
int[][] matrix
```

but use some custom method to set entries; this method would perform some check against additional members

```
int maximum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int minimum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

and replace them if necessary. Such a method could be implemented as follows, and maximum and minimum would be accessible in the members above.

```
void setEntry(int i, int j, in value)
{
    matrix[i][j] = value;
    minimum = Math.min(value, minimum);
    maximum = Math.max(value, maximum);
}
```

However, this approach basically would trade the time for searching the matrix for time setting up the matrix entries.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'm not deeply immersed in the conventions.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can't do better then O(n^2) ; since the numbers are not sorted , or do not have any particular property (like all of them fit into a certain range, for example), you must access every single number, to make sure if it does/doesn't modify the value of the existing maximum/minimum. accessing all the numbers gives n^2 operations

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach is to convert a two dimensional array to 1D list and use Stream API to get the min and max value.

We would have use `Integer` array as against `int` array in the above code. Consider the following implementation. The number of lines of code is decreased.

```
            Integer[][] matrix = {
            {10, 10, 10, 10, -10},
            {20, 20, 20, -20, 20},
            {30, 30, -30, 30, 30},
            {40, -40, 40, 40, 40},
            {-50, 50, 50, 50, 50}};

            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (Integer[] array : matrix)
                list.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));
            int max = list.stream().max((p1, p2) -> p1.compareTo(p2)).get().intValue();
            int min = list.stream().min((p1, p2) -> p1.compareTo(p2)).get().intValue();
            System.out.println("MIN: " + min);
            System.out.println("MAX: " + max);
```

Answer (score 0):

*This isn't exactly the answer to the question* but I think it sheds some light and gives some theoretical improvement.

If you want a O(n) complexity time, you should change you nested iteration for-loop:

```
 //in O(n^2)
 for (int[] ints : matrix) {
            for (int i : ints) {
                if (i < min) {
                    min = i;
                }
                if (i > max) {
                    max = i;
                }
            }
        }
```

To something like:

```
for(i = 0; i<(X*Y); i++)
```

In you case `X = 5,Y = 5;` and then iterate.

Comment: Yes, for a small n. But with just one loop when you will be iterating over (X x Y)  it will be O(n) cause you are not restarting your iteration at any point of time. Otherwise  for each iteration of the outer loop the inner loop runs n times.

Comment: for a nxm matrix, in the op's example there are n outer loops and m inner loops => nxm iterations. In your example there are nxm iterations too. In the end, unless the matrix has some specific characteristics, you need to inspect all elements, so you need nxm checks. Whether you use nested loop or a single loop makes no difference to the time complexity...

Answer (score 0):

**Or you can easilly use lambdas to find the min and max of your array like below :**

```
public int getTheMaxOfRow(int matrix[][], int row) {
    return Arrays.stream(matrix).skip(row).limit(1).flatMapToInt(d -> Arrays.stream(d)).max().getAsInt();
}

public int getTheMinOfRow(int matrix[][], int row) {
    return Arrays.stream(matrix).skip(row).limit(1).flatMapToInt(d -> Arrays.stream(d)).min().getAsInt();
 }
```